# I'm trying to update a post as a user using SQLite and PHP, first fetch the post ID and then update the post, but it doesn't work

Tags: php, sqlite, post, get, sql-update

In index.php
I have a list of posts and want to fetch the ID of post, while clicking on the link below

```
<div class="editPost">
    <a href="updatePost.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">Edit</a> </div>
```

In updatePost.php

I want to define the ID of post and update the post in the form at the same time, but I don't know if it's possible, or if there is another way

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $userId = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);


        if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['description'])) {
            $title = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $link = filter_var($_POST['link'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $description = filter_var($_POST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



            $query = 'UPDATE posts
                              SET title = :title,
                                  link = :link,
                                  description = :description,
                                  userId = :userId
                             WHERE id = :id';

            $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

            if (!$statement) {
                die(var_dump($pdo->errorInfo()));
            }


            $statement->bindParam(':id ', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':userId ', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $statement->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Form in html file

```
 <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Your post's title" required>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Please write the title*</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="link">Link</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="link" name="link" id="link" required>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Please write the link*</small>
        </div>

        <div class="description">
            <label for="description">Description </label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="" required></textarea>
            <small class="form-text text-muted"> Tell us what do your think!*</small>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

I get this error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range.
'I'm new in PHP and SQLite'

Answer (score 0):

That error usually indicates a mismatch between the parameter names used in the query and parameter names in the bindings.

Typo in these two lines:

```
$statement->bindParam(':id ', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':userId ', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Notice the extra space in the parameter names.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out